# Why do I get this line between Containers?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Why do I get a line the color of the image on the bottom of the stack between Containers x and y? And what can I do to avoid that line?[print of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h6gz.jpg)
I want to have a Container with the standard background color and another one that has the fade effect and both these Containers are supposed to be on top of the background Image**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FluxoPermissaoNotificacoes fluxo = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as FluxoPermissaoNotificacoes;
    DataPermissaoNotificacoes data = getDataPermissaoNotificacoes(fluxo);
    return Scaffold(body: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Stack(children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 38,  left: 0),
              child: Container(child: Image.asset("assets/images/permissao_notificacoes.png")),
            ),
            Positioned(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3, child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 46.0),
                child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(13)),
                    color: Color(0xffEBEBEB)), child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                        Row(children: [
                          ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)), child: Image.asset(F.logoSquare ?? 'assets/applogo/android_logo_acad.png', width: 17,)),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                            child: Text(F.nomeApp, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFCompact', color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          ),
                          
                        ],),
                        SizedBox(height: 8,),
                        Text('A sua próxima aula irá começar em meia hora', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFCompact', color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
                      ],),
                    ),),
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
        
        
        Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            //container x
            Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.29,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  colors: GetIt.I.get<ControladorApp>().themeMode == ThemeMode.dark ? [
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                  ] : [
                    Color(0xffFAFAFA).withOpacity(0.0),
                    Color(0xffFAFAFA).withOpacity(0.1),
                    Color(0xffFAFAFA).withOpacity(0.25),
                    Color(0xffFAFAFA).withOpacity(0.5),
                    Color(0xffFAFAFA).withOpacity(0.8),
                    Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                    Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //container y
            Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 12,),
                  TextHeader(data.headText, textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                  SizedBox(height: 16,),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                    child: TextBody1(data.bodyText, textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24,),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: BotaoPrimario(onTap: () {}, value: "Permitir Notificações",),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8,),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: BotaoPrimario(onTap: () {
                      _controladorNotificacao.onTapAgoraNao();
                    }, value: "Agora não", bordered: true, textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, corDefault: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 32,),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html

Comment: It worked just adding the Divider widget between the 2 Containers, I have no idea why but thank you so much :)